# Changing property of control defines in template

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, material-design-in-xaml

I want to access`BackgroundEllipse` of `MaterialDesignClock` which defines in [MaterialDesignTheme.Clock.xaml](https://github.com/MaterialDesignInXAML/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit/blob/master/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.Clock.xaml)

After accessing the `Ellipse`, I need to change the opacity of `BackgroundEllipse`.

The sample code below did not work.

```
<materialDesign:Clock x:Name="MaterialTimePicker" Is24Hours="True" 
                    BorderThickness="0" >
    <materialDesign:Clock.Style>
        <Style>
            <Setter TargetName="BackgroundEllipse" Property="Opacity" Value="1" />
        </Style>
    </materialDesign:Clock.Style>
</materialDesign:Clock>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot change the `Opacity` of the `Ellipse` that is included in the template in XAML without copying the *entire* template and edit it. The value of the `Opacity` is hardcoded to `0.23`.

You may change it dynamically though:

```
private void MaterialTimePicker_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Clock clock = (Clock)sender;
    Ellipse ellipse = clock.Template.FindName("BackgroundEllipse", clock) as Ellipse;
    if (ellipse != null)
    {
        ellipse.Opacity = 1.0;
    }
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<materialDesign:Clock x:Name="MaterialTimePicker" Is24Hours="True" BorderThickness="0"
    Loaded="MaterialTimePicker_Loaded"/>
```

This requires a lot less markup than the XAML solution of copying the template.